# PackT book - Advanced Express Web App Dev

Tags: express, mocha.js

I am running into a MOCHA problem in reference to the book, Chapter 1, during the first run of MOCHA test.  it saying that my /heartbeat is undefined and not a function.  I have copied the book, and I have even backed dependencies back down to what the book used (not what is most current) and still having a failure.  I have my development upto the point of the failure in the book on github here (https://github.com/EnergeticPixels/expressWebAppDev_packt.git).  Can anyone help point me out my mistake???  It has to be something simple.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

totally my fault.  I missed a darn comma following the function name in the express/index.js file.  Told ya it was a simple mistake.